# ¿Pueden varias funciones en paralelo escribir datos en dynamo db?

Tags: python-3.x, aws, lambda, async, dynamodb

ejecucion sin funciones paralelas: time=x

ejecucion con 4 funciones paralelas: time=x/4

Cuando se ejecuta el codigo adjuntado con 4 funciones paralelas el timpo total no se divide para 4, sino que se mantiene.

mi pregunta es:
Dynamodb soporta escrituras de tabla de funciones paralelas?

```py
def patronfanin_out(event, context):
    for i in range(4):
        x= list #aqui envio una lista nueva para cada función
        response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="tesis-aws-patrones-dev-workers",
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(x)
      )

def workers(event, context):
  table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('patron2')
  rowsFinal = event['list']
  for row in rowsFinal:
    table.put_item(Item={
        'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
        'serie': row[0],
        'rank': row[1],
        'discipline': row[2],
        'sex': row[3],
        'salary': row[4]
        })
  response = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "params" : rowsFinal
  }
  return response
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta, pues estás en SO en español

Comment: El ejemplo de código que has puesto entiendo que es la función "no paralela", pues no veo que estés creando hilos ni usando asincronía. ¿Puedes poner cómo has hecho la versión paralela? Pues es posible que hayas hecho algo mal y en el fondo se esté ejecutando secuencialmente. Si descartamos eso, entonces es claro que la parte secuencial estaría en otro lugar, quizás en el servidor DynamoDB como sospechas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, justamente el código que plantee es una función (patronfanin_out) que llama a otras 4 funciones(workers) de manera asincrona (InvocationType='Event') es decir esta llamando a 4 funciones en paralelo. El código de la función no paralela no lo publique. Pero lo que en realidad deseo saber es si dynamo trabaja de manera paralela en las escrituras de las tablas.